# How to extract zip file without leading source path in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to unzip the file in php without leading source path. 
I have a zip file let say /var/www/test/myproj/storage/data.zip

and when I say:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$x   = $zip->open(storage_path("data.zip"));
$zip->extractTo(storage_path("final"));
```

Then files is extracted with leading source path means files are extracted as: /var/www/test/myproj/storage/final/var/www/test/myproj/storage/file1.....

But I want as /var/www/test/myproj/storage/final/file1...

Comment: but without using storage_path() we can't locate the file

Comment: Have you tried checking the ZIP file? Does it contain the files in its root folder?

Comment: yes...............